# Getting weird gap between svg and div

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make a wavy background kind of transition but im getting this weird gap (its not from padding of margin but its kind off hard to see in inspect element because its so small)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="#36393D" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L18.5,202.7C36.9,213,74,235,111,202.7C147.7,171,185,85,222,74.7C258.5,64,295,128,332,176C369.2,224,406,256,443,234.7C480,213,517,139,554,128C590.8,117,628,171,665,181.3C701.5,192,738,160,775,128C812.3,96,849,64,886,85.3C923.1,107,960,181,997,186.7C1033.8,192,1071,128,1108,85.3C1144.6,43,1182,21,1218,64C1255.4,107,1292,213,1329,250.7C1366.2,288,1403,256,1422,240L1440,224L1440,320L1421.5,320C1403.1,320,1366,320,1329,320C1292.3,320,1255,320,1218,320C1181.5,320,1145,320,1108,320C1070.8,320,1034,320,997,320C960,320,923,320,886,320C849.2,320,812,320,775,320C738.5,320,702,320,665,320C627.7,320,591,320,554,320C516.9,320,480,320,443,320C406.2,320,369,320,332,320C295.4,320,258,320,222,320C184.6,320,148,320,111,320C73.8,320,37,320,18,320L0,320Z" style="height:100%;width:100%;line-height: 0;overflow:hidden;font-size: 0"></path>
      </svg>
<footer style="padding-bottom:6px;">
  <div style="text-align: center;color: white;background-color: #36393D;padding-top:20px">
```

This is also with bootstrap enabled so idk if that might cause some confusion
Anyways the image of the gap: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnTYb.png)

Comment: @j08691, could you edit again the snippet ? Its content is buggy because of a missing `"` at then end of `<div style="text-align: center;color: white;background-color: #36393D;padding-top:20px>`

Comment: @Philippe sure, done

Comment: @Philippe Hey! Thanks for responding, weirdly enough I fixed it by just adding wrapping it to a div and giving a div a height

Comment: Thanks @j08691 :) Great HamsterRecords ! :)